# Need to update Swift code to the newest version

Tags: ios, swift

Prior to the new Swift version I was using the following code in my app.
Now it launches an exception.

```
for (i, in 0 ..< len){
            let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
            let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
            randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
        }
```

XCode says:

- Expected pattern
- Expected "," separator
- Expected "in" after for-each pattern
- Expected SequenceType expression for for-each loop

Changing the code with the proposed solutions doesn't change the exceptions thrown.

Any help is welcome to update the code to the current Swift version.

Comment: you are converting in swift 2.2 right ?

Comment: @Pyro, I uploaded the app last week and it was working fine. I guess that after the new update on 21st march to version 2.2, some part of my code has been deprecated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `for` syntax you are using have been deprecated, and should be changed to

```
for _ in 0..<len
    // rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank you Claus, let me check your proposal.

Answer (score 2):

the question already has correct answer still i have converted it so posting here may be some get help from it

```
let len = 5
let letters:NSString = "str"
for i in 0 ..< len {
    let length = UInt32 (letters.length)
    let rand = arc4random_uniform(length)
    let randomString:NSMutableString = ""
    randomString.appendFormat("%C", letters.characterAtIndex(Int(rand)))
}
```

As some of the variable are not shown in the code i have made them based on the parameters